# How to integrate AngularJS with Dojo 1.6?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dojo, angularjs-1.6

Does someone know a pratical way to integrate AngularJS with Dojo 1.6?
I already found a solution which combines Dojo 1.7 with AngularJS. Dojo 1.7 works fine with AngularJS. But Dojo 1.6 seems to be far more complicated. 
Background: Sometimes you have an enterprise application based on Dojo 1.6 and you are not allowed to change the frameworks itself, but you want to profit from modern frameworks. Hope that gives a hint of the motivation for the question.